# When $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 2$ is divided by $g(x)$ which is a polynomial with integer coefficient, the quotient and remainder are both $h(x)$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, problem-solving, cubics

So here is the Question :-

When $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 2$ is divided by $g(x)$ which is a polynomial with integer coefficient, the quotient and remainder are both $h(x)$ . Given that $h(x)$ is not a constant, find $g$ and $h$.

**What I tried** :- Since the Quotient and Remainder are both $h(x)$ , we get :- $$f(x) = g(x)h(x) + h(x)$$
$$ \implies x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 2 = h(x) [g(x) + 1]$$

Now $f(x)$ can be factorised as $(x^2 + x + 2)(x + 1)$ . So I can conclude that :-

Either $$h(x) = x^2 + x + 2 , g(x) = x$$
Or $$h(x) = x + 1 , g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$$

I am sure I am quite done with the problem , but from here I don't know what to do next . Can Anyone help?

Comment: What do you know about the degrees of the divisor and the remainder modulo that divisor?

Comment: I know modular arithmetic and about the degree of a divisor . If u are asking Factor Theorem or Rational Root Theorem then in that sense yes .

Comment: I mean, in $a(x) = q(x)b(x) + r(x)$ generally, what do you know about $\deg b$ and $\deg r$?

Comment: Um , I don't have that knowledge though

Comment: It's part of the statement of the division algorithm (say in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, if we look at only a ring for the coefficients rather than a field something extra is needed). "If $b \neq 0$, then for every $a$ there are _uniquely determined_ $q$ and $r$ such that $a(x) = q(x)b(x) + r(x)$ and [some condition with degrees]". What is that condition?

Comment: Oh , I know division algorithm but I don't know that condition . Can u tell me please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing to finish is that in a division with remainder we (almost always) require the remainder to be smaller (in some appropriate sense) than the divisor. For division of polynomials with remainder, the appropriate sense is that the degree of the remainder shall be smaller than the degree of the divisor. (If you follow a convention that doesn't assign a negative degree to the zero polynomial, read "the remainder is $0$ or has smaller degree".)

Thus here we have $\deg h < \deg g$, and $h(x) = x+1$, $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ is the solution.

Comment: Oh yeah right . It was so simple ! I knew it before that the remainder is always less than the divisor. But thanks for pointing that out :) .